# Confusions modeling times of related events

Tags: probability, modeling, posterior

I am currently interested in modelling the time of related events, and I am currently confused as to how to incorporate all different sources of information in a single model.

Consider a toy example with two events $A, B$ which happen at times $Y_A, Y_B$ respectively. We may have information on when these events may have happened, for example we may know they have happen within a given interval ($I_A = [l_A,u_A], I_B = [l_B, l_B]$.
Without additional information, we may assume that $Y_A \sim U(I_A) $ and $Y_B \sim U(I_B)$. Equivalently:
$$p_{Y_A,Y_B}(y_A, y_B) \propto \mathbf{1}[y_A \in I_A] \cdot \mathbf{1}[y_B \in I_B]. $$

Now, the confusion comes from adding an additional piece of information. We know some events are successive to each other and the difference between successive events is Gamma distributed.
For example, consider a case in which $B$ is successive to $A$ (denoted as $A \rightarrow B$), and we know that the difference between events is Gamma distributed with pdf $g$.

I previously modelled this extra information with the "posterior":
$$ p_{Y_A,Y_B}(y_A, y_B | A \rightarrow B ) \propto p_{Y_A,Y_B}(y_A, y_B)  \cdot \mathbf{1}[y_B > y_A] \cdot g(y_B - y_A) $$

$$ \quad \propto \mathbf{1}[y_A \in I_A] \cdot \mathbf{1}[y_B \in I_B] \cdot \mathbf{1}[y_B > y_A] \cdot g(y_B - y_A). $$

However, someone raised the point that I am "overspecifying" the distribution of $(Y_A, Y_B)$ as the "prior" on $Y_A$ and $Y_B - Y_A$ are enough to specify the distribution.
However, I do want to incorporate the fact that the range of possible time of events $B$ and $A$ may be very small and informative.

To conclude, I am not sure what I did is valid, and I would appreaciate some feedback. If someone also knew papers considering such modelling such related events, it would be great to read them. Thank you!